# Postman Test Script - Check that the status is NOT 200

Tags: rest, api, unit-testing, testing, postman

I'm creating a script to test my API, I want to check that if the user doesn't enter the correct username and password, the access is denied.

I want my test to pass when the status code is 401. Postman displays a test failure because the status code of my request is not 200.

I actually WANT my response to be 401 in order to pass the test.

Any idea on how to operate ?

Cheers

I tried using this test:

```
pm.test("Status code is 401", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(401);
});
```

This test passes, but Postman is displaying a failed assertion:

```
 response is ok | AssertionError: expected response to have status code
 200 but got 401
```

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have another test checking for a 200? Can you post an image of what you have in Postman?

Comment: @Danny Dainton thanks for replying, here we  go : https://ibb.co/bW8wgx. And nope, I have only one checking if the status is 401

Comment: That tab says that you have unsaved changes - Did you have a 200 test in there before, maybe from the snippets template? Or is there a test at the folder/collection level being run? http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/13/keep-it-dry-with-collection-and-folder-elements/

Comment: I restarted postman to be sure no 200 test have been done before and that no other test are being run. But i kept getting this fail. Here is another screenshot : https://ibb.co/i0uSMx

Comment: Have you checked the Collection for any tests hiding in there? On the Collection folder hit 'Edit' and this will show you a new window that has a 'Tests' tab - The same can be done at the subfolder level.

Comment: I just checked, and unfortunately nothing is written in the test section of each folder and sub folders...

Comment: Have you tried creating and running a separate test outside of the collection to check this is happening there? Or commenting out everything in the tests section, saving this and running the request.

Comment: It worked! thanks a million !!

Comment: Which part? If it worked outside of the collection I would look at the collection closer to see where this test is coming from.

Comment: I created a new folder and re-created the test from scratch and it worked. It's the first time that I use postman, so maybe i twicked something wrong when setting up the script and/or the runner

Comment: I would suggest adding your solution as an answer and marking the question as answered or it will leave it open. Glad you found sound that works.

Comment: all right, i will do it. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new folder and started again from scratch and it worked. I wasn't able to find where the problem was coming from though...

Answer (score 0):

The parent folder may have the "200" test configured in it - thus inheriting it.